# Only assignment, call, increment

Tags: c#

```
double number;
string message;

Console.WriteLine("Welcome and enter a number.");
number = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (number < 0)
    message = "Your number is Negative";
else
    (number > = 0)
    message = "Your number is Positive"; 

Console.WriteLine(message);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I'm making this program for a class in school, and I'm getting an error with the line: (number > = 0) I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The error message says

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement.

Comment: based on the error, the space is most likely a typo in the question.  The error would be different if the operator were causing the problem.

Answer (score 9):

`else` statements cannot have a conditional applied to them, they simply run if every `if` and `else if` in the same "block" does not run.

So your conditional expression doesn't make sense, and is read as a statement to the compiler (which it is not).

Simply make your `else` an `else if` to fix the error:

```
   else if(number >= 0)
        message = "Your number is Positive";
```

Or just remove the conditional, since a number not less than 0 *must* be greater than or equal to 0.

```
   else
        message = "Your number is Positive";
```

Comment: there's still a space between the '>' and '=' which shouldn't be there, but aside from that, this is a good, helpful answer.

Comment: No, @Habib, it won't be ignored.

Comment: It won't compile with the space because > and = are both operators distinct from >=

Comment: Fixed the OP's typo :)

Comment: Minor quibble, but `number = double.NaN` will result in false for both `(number < 0)` and `(number >= 0)`.  Probably not something the OP should worry about, but an interesting thing to keep in mind when writing code with doubles where NaNs might sneak in by mistake.  This can sometimes result in subtle bugs down the line as the NaNs result in various unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a condition in else part with `if`. In fact you don't need that at all. Since that is the cause of error so change `else  (number > = 0)` to just `else`. Also Use `{}` to define scopes for `if` and `else` part.

So your code should look like:

```
double number;
string message = null;

Console.WriteLine("Welcome and enter a number.");
number = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (number < 0)
{
    message = "Your number is Negative";
}
else
{
    message = "Your number is Positive";
}

Console.WriteLine(message);
Console.ReadLine();
```

`{}` would be useful/required if you want multiple statements to be part of `if` or `else` block. Just having that for single statement is optional but probably a good practice, IMO.

You should also look for `double.TryParse` or `TryParse` group of methods for parsing, since they will not raise an exception in case of failed parsing, like:

```
if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
    return;// early exit or use a loop to ask again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Students will learn == sign too

```
        double number;
        string message = "";

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome and enter a number.");
        number = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (number < 0)
        {
            message = "Your number is Negative";
        }
        else if(number == 0)
        {
            message = "Your number is Zero";
        }
        else
        {
            message = "Your number is Positive";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(message);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

mark answer